# Codeigniter ciqrcode issue linux

Tags: codeigniter

I have hosted my codeigniter application on linux, here i am facing problem for  generation qrcode. Its giving FCPATH error
but if i am running it on windows wampserver its running fine.

HERE is my code

```
$this->load->library('ciqrcode');
$params['data'] = 'my qr code image';
$params['level'] = 'H';
$params['size'] = 10;
$params['savename'] = FCPATH.'public/qrcode/image.png';
$this->ciqrcode->generate($params);
```

Comment: You should check your linux path.

Comment: will you please tell me FCPath??

Comment: You can reference this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992074/codeigniter-path-functions-definitions

Comment: my index.php is same as it display in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992074/codeigniter-path-functions-definitions

Comment: You can try to remove FCPATH.

Comment: I had tried this also..

Comment: Could you show your error message?