# Codeigniter 3, Load data infile, fcpath

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Im doing Load Data Infile I've got this code

```
 move_uploaded_file($file_temp,"uploads/master_listing/".$file_name);

 $file_path = FCPATH.'/uploads/master_listing/'.$file_name;

 $this->db->query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$file_path."' 
   INTO TABLE fsi_temp_newmasterlist 
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
   LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' 
   IGNORE 1 LINES
   (SEQUENCENUMBER,NAME,ADDRESS,PICKUPDATE,ENCODERNO,BARCODEVALUE,REMARKS,CLIENT,PROD)
 ");
```

I dont know what's wrong in that code I got error `Can't find file`

Here's my file location `myfolder/uploads/master_listing/`

My csv file has table head of `SEQUENCENUMBER,NAME,ADDRESS,PICKUPDATE,ENCODERNO,BARCODEVALUE,REMARKS,CLIENT,PROD`

I really need help.. thanks in advance.

Comment: `echo $file_path` and check

Comment: I get this C:\xampp5.5\htdocs\joel_fsi\fsi2/uploads/master_listing/testfileupload.csv

Comment: I've replace location to the real path but it still give me error LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\xampp5.5\htdocs\joel_fsi\fsi2\uploads\master_listing\testfileupload.csv'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
$new_name = str_replace("\\","/",$file_path)
```

after replace

```
C:/xampp5.5/htdocs/joel_fsi/fsi2/uploads/master_listing/testfileupload.csv
```

In your code

```
 C:\xampp5.5\htdocs\joel_fsi\fsi2/uploads/master_listing/testfileupload.csv
```

They are conflict `\` and `/`

> Take look at this [Codeigniter path functions definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992074/codeigniter-path-functions-definitions)

Comment: $new_name = str_replace("\","/",$file_path) is error

Comment: `str_replace` should be `"\\"`