# Unlink file - path issue - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, unlink

Apparently, I am confused how to use `site_url`() while deleting a file.

My site_url responded with `http://localhost/Project/index.php`

For deleting a file, I use `unlink` command. However, How to use `site_url` into the `unlink` command in `codeigniter`. I am surprised!

Below is the path where the uploaded files get stored!

```
$config['upload_path']      = './assets/images';
```

I have used the following:

```
unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/NetSach/assets/images/".$_FILES['picture']['name']);
```

**Message:** unlink(C:/xampp/htdocs/NetSach/assets/images/sweepers cartoon.jpg): No such file or directory

Comment: Down-voters mind commenting before giving down-vote!

Comment: unlink means delete the file.
What is the connection between deleting the file and the URL?
* I'm not the one who voted down *

Comment: @EdenMoshe I need to delete the file from the folder itself and then update it with the new file. So, I need to set the url path. Hope it makes sense!

Comment: The documentation says: [*filename: Path to the file.*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php#refsect1-function.unlink-parameters) not *URL to the file*. Also note that it is a bad habit to ask why people are downvoting: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285081/am-i-still-supposed-to-explain-my-downvotes-or-not/285777

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Agreed on down-vote.  Between, How to pass the URL to the unlink(). Any idea?

Comment: You don't. You are not removing an url, you are removing an actual file on the filesystem of your server.

Comment: You probably want to use `FCPATH`, or one of the other [path constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992074/codeigniter-path-constants-definitions).

Comment: What people are failing to tell you is that there is a difference between a file's _URL_ and its _path_ (that is, its location _on disk_). An URL might be `https://www.sample.com/sample.html` but the actual path might be `/var/www/html/sample.html`. So it's not so simple to identify a file's path based on its URL.  But the solution is easy. Just use `unlink($config['upload_path'] . '/' . $filename);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about the innocent question. I hope I understood the question than others would!
However, I tried the below and found it working finally!

```
unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/project_folder/assets/images/'.$res['image_url']);
```

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` // Gives the root path of the project folder successfully.

I use the codeigniter way of the path. i.e.) The `base_url()` is not working in the `unlink` because it will not accept `https://`

I hope this answer will be useful to someone!